# Substituting alphanumeric substrings with single unicode from a table

Tags: python, regex, string, unicode, substitution

Given the input:

```
nguye64n tra62n huye62n my
```

Desired output:

```
nguyễn trần huyền my
```

I've been doing it with a substitute table and iterating each character to look for the digits, cache them and translate them when it is followed by a non-digit character:

```
substitute = {'e64': u'ễ', 'a62': u'ầ', 'e62': 'ề'}
s = 'nguye64n tra62n huye62n my'
tonal = ''
x = ''
for ch in s:
    if ch.isdigit():
        tonal += ch
    else:
        if tonal:
            tonal = substitute[x[-1] + tonal]
            x = x[:-1] + tonal
            tonal = ''
        x += ch
```

[out]:

```
>>> x
'nguyễn trần huyền my'
```

**Is there a simpler way to achieve the same output given the substitution table?** Maybe regex substitutions or some `str.translate` operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `re.sub` can be used to replace a match according to a function.  Here I've used a lambda function to process the match and replace it from the lookup table:

```
#coding:utf8
import re

substitute = {'e64': u'ễ', 'a62': u'ầ', 'e62': 'ề'}
s = 'nguye64n tra62n huye62n my'
x = re.sub(r'[a-z]\d+',lambda m: substitute[m.group(0)],s)
print(x)
```

> nguyễn trần huyền my

Comment: if you use `substitute.get(m.group[0], m.group[0])` instead of `substitute[m.group(0)]` you will not get `KeyError` when there is no match in the dict and it will return the original text. This might or might not be wanted behaviour